# How to calculate a spanning axis of rotation of a linear map given the rotational transformation matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Not going to lie, I haven't paid much attention in my Linear Algebra course this term.

I'm working on a problem where I need to find the invariant vector or spanning axis of rotation of a given rotational matrix in $\mathbb{R^3}$. My matrix is as follows:
$$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2/3 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\
-2/3 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\
1/3 & -2/3 & 2/3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have tried approaching this by calculating the eigenvalues using $\det(A- \lambda I) = 0$ as if I can get the eigenvectors, I'll have the invariant vectors (I think) but this route became super messy as eigenvalues came out as irrational numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $x$ is a vector along the axis of the rotation, then it should satisfy $Ax = x$.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  Just set $\lambda = 1$, then you want to solve

$ \begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{3} && \dfrac{2}{3} && \dfrac{1}{3} \\
-\dfrac{2}{3} && -\dfrac{2}{3} && \dfrac{2}{3} \\
\dfrac{1}{3} && -\dfrac{2}{3} && -\dfrac{1}{3} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = 0 $

The third equation is a multiple (by $(-1)$ ) of the first equation.  So now you have only two equations.  After multiplying through by $(3)$,

$ - x_1 + 2 x_2 + x_3 = 0 \hspace{10pt}(1)$

and

$ - x_1 - x_2 + x_3 = 0 \hspace{10pt}(2) $

Adding $(-1) \times $  Eq.$(1)$ to Eq.$(2)$, gives us

$ -3 x_2 = 0 $, so that $x_2 = 0 $.  Plugging this in either equation, gives

$x_1 = x_3$

Therefore, the solution vector is

$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = t \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

where $t $ is arbitrary.  Hence the axis unit vector is

$ a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Thank you! I was getting too caught up on the eigenvalues. Still am not quite sure where $\lambda = 1$ comes from. Is it arbitrary?

Comment: No. It's not arbitrary.  The reason why it is $1$ is that when apply the rotation matrix to a vector that is on its axis of rotation, the image is the same vector you started with, i.e. $A x = x $, which translates into $(A - (1) I) x = 0 $ .  Since $x$ is a non-zero vector, then det(A - I) = 0, and $1$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.